# How to deal with (presumable) UTF-8 strings in C programs on OSX

Tags: c, macos, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

Hopefully the question title describes my issue well enough.

Platform: OSX 10.8, llvm with clang++ compiler

I have got a directory with filenames in Japanese or Cyrillic characters. Those filenames are displayed correctly (e.g. via `ls`) in iTerm2 with en_EN.UTF-8 locale and Monaco 10 font (not sure if locale/font make a difference, but it seems it should). A vanilla xterm without UTF-8 support, however, prints scrambled symbols or '?' characters for non-ASCII characters.

*Here is the actual question:*

In C++ program, I use `readdir()` from `dirent.h` to list the contents of a directory containing filenames in Japanese or Cyrillic characters. Printing the `d_name` property of the `struct dirent` result of `readdir()` displays the correct characters in the Xcode terminal. That is, e.g. Japanese kanji really are displayed as such.
Same is true when executing the program from iTerm2. Again, scrambled characters in non-UFT-8 xterm.

- Since the byte size of Japanese filenames does not equal the number
  of characters displayed, I boldly assume, the `dirent.h` functions work
  with UTF-8 strings. Is it possible that all of the OSX C-Library
  works that way?
- Therefor, is it safe to e.g. alter the `struct dirent.d_name` or
  `strcpy` it and create a new file using that altered string? Is it possible to step in some trap that leads to '?????' filenames being written instead of kanji?
- Would setting a different locale, e.g. "C", mess things up (does not
  seem that way when using `setlocale(LC_ALL,"C")`).

Note: I am not interested in possible 3rd party alternatives to dirent.h. I wrote the program solely to shed some light on how OSX deals with locale and character encoding.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is designed to be backwards-compatible with ASCII from the point of view of legacy string-handling code. This includes `strcpy()` and friends.

So yes, in your code it's generally safe to handle these strings as you would any other string<sup>*</sup>; it's only at display time that the clever stuff happens.

<sup>* as long as you're not meddling with individual characters in the string.</sup>

Comment: You should mention that strlen() won't return the amount of real characters in the string, but rather the amount of bytes. Also, searching for an ASCII character or string inside a UTF-8 string will work just fine. And modifying that specific character or string will work too.

Answer (score 1):

A valid UTF8 string doesn't contain any null characters, so any string operations should work on UTF8 encoded strings. You probably do not want to take substrings of it or modify the bytes in it though, since some of the characters are encoded in multiple bytes.

Most of the APIs which handle `char*` are not aware and doesn't care about the encoding, so they should be safe to use.

setlocale will affect [certain operations](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/), mostly related to dealing with character types, ordering, and formatting.

When you print the string, it goes out as a bunch of bytes. The terminal emulator interprets it as UTF8 and pick the correct characters. xterm, being unaware of unicode, will of course not be able to interpret it correctly and display the proper characters.

Comment: So printing my string is deferred to the terminal. If I happen to printf a JIS encoded string, the terminal has to support it. But how about reading from my directory? Why does readdir work correctly, filling the d_name buffer with an UTF-8 string? Is this something that is guaranteed for by the C library (or at least the one llvm provides)?

Comment: readdir doesn't care what encoding the name is in, it just so happens that HFS+ (the filesystem OSX uses) stores filenames in unicode and hands them off to you in UTF8. If you were using a filesystem that's unaware of encodings and just store whatever bytes in whatever input, then the result will depend on the encoding of the filename when it was written (Windows traditionally has a lot of fun with this, but not so much for Mac).